# Flutter CameraPreview freezes when reopening the app

Tags: flutter, dart, camera

I followed this tutorial here:
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera

Everything works fine but after reopening the app after some time the cameraPreview-part freezes. I read about adding a didChangeAppLifecycleState method but this only caused more problems like a totally black screen when reopening.

flutter doctor: version

```
Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.3, on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS 5.13.0-35-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
```

pubspec.yaml: versions

```
camera: ^0.9.4+16
path: ^1.8.0
path_provider: ^2.0.9
```

I'm mainly running on my Redmi Note 8T but this problem also occurs on my emulator.

TY :)

Comment: I don't use this package, but also have this problem when reading files since Flutter 2.10.x. Have you found a solution or a workaround that is not downgrading?

Comment: @Mäddin Sadly not solved yet.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Unfortunately, I can't help there either. I have now simply removed the affected line of code and hope for a future fix. I would recommend you to downgrade to Flutter 2.8. This is not a long-term solution, but it probably works.